# Select dropdown closing when cursor leaves list in Firefox

Tags: html, reactjs, firefox, input

I have some react code that should just render a select input when given a list. It renders and works fine, however I want to stop the dropdown menu from closing whenever the cursor leaves the list. It also closes when the cursor is moved too quickly within the list.

Here is the code that creates the input.

**MyInput.js**

```
class MyInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.setItem = this.setItem.bind(this)
  }

  const list = () => {
    return [1, 2, 3].map((option) =>
      <option key={option}>{option}</option>
    )
  }

  setItem (event) {
    const item = event.target.value
    this.setState({ item })
  }

  render() {
    const itemSelect =
      <select value={this.state.item} onChange={event => this.setItem(event)}>
        {list}
      </select>

    return ( 
      <div>{itemSelect}</div>
    )
  }
}
```

**styles.css**

```
select:hover {
  filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

This is present in Firefox and works fine in Chrome and IE11. How do I change it so it only closes when the mouse is clicked?

**EDIT:** This only occurs when the `filter: brightness(50%)` style on the `select:hover` is added to the css. CodeSandbox link is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-brown-s4wum (credit to @levis in the comments).

Comment: Provide more code. How and where you have added react? Your `setItem` function and your `list`. Also where you are using `itemSelect`.

Comment: @ravibagul91 I didn't think it was a React thing so left most of it out. I have added it now just in case.

Comment: I fixed the code you posted to make it run on CodeSandbox and tested it on firefox and it works just fine. https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-dhawan-kl6ki 
Are you missing something in the code you posted? if not then your problem is not react related. Maybe CSS? another JS library?

Comment: Thanks @levis, that's working for me too. I did leave a few things out (such as css) to minimise the code. Although I don't know the issue yet, I'll dig through and post back when I find it. Cheers.

Comment: Ok, figured it out @levis. It happens when you add filter: brightness(50%) style on the select:hover in the CSS. I have added the CSS to your CodeSandbox and successfully reproduced it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-brown-s4wum

Comment: @jarthur you need to set the brightness to 100% when the select has no pseudo-class applied. I've updated my codesandbox, have a look

Comment: @levis Great, it works! Thanks again. Do you know why this occurs? If you want to post this as an answer I will mark it as the accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's a bug on Firefox or that mixing pseudo classes and functions are just a bad idea but adding 100% of brightness to the  element fixes it.

```
select{
  filter: brightness(100%);
}

select:hover {
  filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

CodeSandbox working: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-dhawan-kl6ki